# How can I separate categories when writing a new article in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have more than 150 categories and subcategories, and I need this number due to the nature of my site, but I am facing a problem in searching for the appropriate category while writing the article. Is there a way to hide the subcategories, so that the subcategories do not appear until after choosing the main category?

I am use these and include it in JavaScript/jQuery file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Hide all subcategories initially
    $('#categorychecklist input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('children')) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    // Show subcategories when a main category is selected
    $('#categorychecklist input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('category')) {
            var mainCatID = $(this).val();
            $('input[type="checkbox"][value^="' + mainCatID + '"]').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Then paste the provided code in a .js file (e.g., hide-subcategories.js).
Finally, I added the following code to the file  functions.php:

```
function enqueue_hide_subcategories_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('hide-subcategories', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/hide-subcategories.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_hide_subcategories_script');
```

But this did not work and there was no change

Comment: Does it work if you run this jQuery code in the console?

Comment: Are you not using a child theme? If you are, right now you are enqueing a file from the parent theme - In that case, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` insted

Comment: I think it is better to fix that by showing only necessary categories; it will be easier to find them. I recommend you create a dropdown list, and then you can choose the main category in drop-down list and then you can find sub-categories easier.

Comment: @SallarRabiei Yes, but I am not a programmer, can you help me with this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please update your question and add the ID of the main categories, I will give you the function you need to add to `functions.php`